# Filtering table where field like the result of a subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to create a query which finds all usernames which contain the results of a subquery. I've written some pseudo code below:

```
select <field1>
from <table1>
where <field> like 
    ( select <field2> from <table2> )
```

I essentially want to end up with my query comparing :

```
table1.field1 like '%' || table2.field2 || '%'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you can `join` the tables and specify the `like` condition.

Comment: Well, you could write `where <field> like ANY (select '%' || table2.field2 || '%'  from <table2>)`, which will result in an Explain similar to Gordon's `exists`. Hopefully at least one of the tables is small, otherwise the resulting *Product Join* will be very inefficient.

Comment: In the SQL world tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Vamsi Prabhala - Not sure I fully get that, there's nothing to join on other than the fields I'm trying to compare

Comment: dnoeth - Thanks! I'd tried:
where <field> like any '%' || (select table2.field2 from table2) || '%'
but hadn't thought of putting the wildcards inside of the select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select <field1>
from <table1> t1
where exists (select <field2>
              from <table2> t2
              where t1.field1 like '%' || t2.field2 || '%'
             );
```

You could possibly also do this with a `join`, but you might have to remove duplicates afterwards.